# Discord bot wont go online

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

im creating a Discord bot for my server but when i try to make the bot run nothing happens
here is what my code looks like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57491.png)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

 const client = new Discord.Client();



client.once('ready', () => {
console.log('Bot is online')
});



 client.login('MY TOKEN');
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Have you correctly setup your bot and linked it to the server?

Comment: @AidanDonnelly i think i have, i gave the bot admin permissions on my server and i put the token as my client login, what i expected to happen was that the bot would go online and after that i would set up the commands but because the bot didnt fo online i didnt add any commands

Comment: You can see the white circle next to the file name. That means it hasn't been saved. Please to `Ctrl`+`S` and try again

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not reproducible. [OP didn't save the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70152296/discord-bot-wont-go-online/70153739#comment124022545_70153739), that's why it didn't work for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are on v12 because discord.js should automatically throw an error if no intents are specified in the options. As seen in their repo right [here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/main/src/client/Client.js#L543).
So you should update to the latest version (v13.x.x) using `npm install discord.js@latest`.
This requires Node v16.6.0+ so make sure you have that installed.
If this still persists, please consider joining the [support server](https://discord.gg/djs) for further help.

*I just noticed that you haven't saved the file.
Hit **CTRL+S** to save it.*

Comment: no im on 13.3.1, thats why its so weird that nothing happends, no erros and no activation, but thanks for the answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Are you sure you're on v13.3.1? Can you do `npm ls discord.js` in the console?

Comment: yeah i did, it doesnt let me send pics here but ill copy exactly what it says                  PS C:\Users\Custom\Desktop\DiscordBot> npm ls discord.js
discordbot@1.0.0 C:\Users\Custom\Desktop\DiscordBot
└── discord.js@13.3.1

Comment: Can you following some of the guide right [here](https://discordjs.guide)? I have literally no idea what's going on.

Comment: im sorry, i started using visual studio code when i started this project so i didnt know how to use it, the problem what that i didnt save my code, thank you